# PHP to Ajax Post using JQuery, global events work but the POST never seems to get set properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I'm attempting to use the $.ajax call to post data to a form.  The event is triggered when there is a change to the value of an input form.  For simplicity's sake, I put everything on C9.io so that all of my code can be seen.

http://c9.io/noman2000/php-ajax

Here is the script that begins the function:

```
<?php 
    // Strictly for a demo, this isn't how it is actually written.
    ?>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="user-name">
    </form>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxGlobaltests.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $jQ(document).ready(function() {

                /* 
                The DOMNodeInserted is a wonky event at best.  This should be refactored to a function that is exited upon
                completion and that uses SetInterval to prevent it from firing too often and killing page speed.
                But this is just a demo.
                */
                $jQ(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
                        var element = e.target;


                        var userName = $jQ('#user-name');
                        console.log(userName.val());
                        if(userName){
                            userName.on('change', function(){
                                $jQ(this).css('background-color', '#EEE');
                                $jQ.ajax({
                                url: 'submit.php',
                                type: 'post',
                                data: {action: userName.val()}
                                // .serialize() is used for multiple values, but I think this will work for singular.
                                }).done(function(){
                                    console.log('It has been done.');
                                }); // end ajax call
                                return false;
                            });//End change
                        }//End if
                }); //End DOM Node Insert
            }); // End on Ready.
                            </script>
```

The submit.php script for catching this AJAX event:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['action'])
    {
        $user_info['username'] = 'test data';
          ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // C9 registers and Error pushing between javascript and php, but this works fine in production.
    console.log(<?php echo "The post data is  {$_POST['action']} and the userID is {$user_info['username']}"; ?>);
    </script>


    <?php

        if(class_exists('dbde_mysql')){
            $uName_db = new dbde_mysql;
             $uName_connect = mysqli_connect($uName_db->host, $uName_db->user, $uName_db->pass, $uName_db->db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($uName_db));
             $uName_str = "UPDATE users SET {$_POST['action']} WHERE id = {$user_id}";
             $sql_res = mysqli_query($uName_db, $uName_str) or die("sql error: $uName_str\n");
     }else{
         // Future proofing.  This ensures that a new database can be created if the class doesn't exist.
         // uName is connected, not a problem.  On this demo, yes, it obviously doesn't work.
         ?>

         <?php
     }


    } // Post action field.
    ?>
```

Both my global Ajax event register shows the code beginning and executing, no errors.  The .done event fires off the console message as well.  However, nothing inside the submit.php seems to do anything.   So is my $_POST['action'] variable correct or am I missing something else here?

Comment: In update query, you have specify the field name in ` SET {$_POST['action']} `

Comment: however you will get sql error in ajax response.

Comment: Have you inspected the response of the post?

Comment: It's the little things that kill.  You're right.  I'll test it and see if that's the problem.

Comment: For Patrick Q, how do you inspect an Ajax event?  If I knew how, I would do it in a heartbeat, but the only thing I can find are global event registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of your PHP file to see what you are receiving:

```
//if HTML recd, otherwise handle for type Eg. die(json_encode($_POST['action']));
die( $_POST['action'] );
```

Then, in your `.done()` function, display what you received:

```
.done(function(retd){
    //If HTML received, otherwise handle for type
    console.log('Received: ' + retd);
});
```

This will allow you to see what is being received at the PHP side, at least.

---

Further down you could add:

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql_res);
die(' Received rows: ' . $num_rows);
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some debug information.  It is receiving exactly what it's supposed to be receiving.  I'm thinking I must have a SQL error that's preventing this from working.

Comment: Perhaps add a test after the mysqli_query and see how many rows were returned.  Echo that out..? See update to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help.  Part 1 was to store the old value into a .data object.

```
var userName = $jQ('#user-name');
                    console.log(userName.val());
                    if((userName) && (typeof userName !== 'undefined')){
                    if(userName.val() !== ''){
                        //Using the .data object to retrieve this the first time is becomes available.
                        userName.data('oldVal',  userName.val() );
                        // To avoid this problem on add new user, then the 
                        // other necessary values should be tested.
                        userName.on('change', function(){
                            $jQ(this).css('background-color', '#EEE');
                            $jQ.ajax({
                            url: 'submit.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {action: userName.val(),
                                   oldval: userName.data('oldVal') 
                            }
                            // .serialize() is used for multiple values, but I think this will work for singular.
                            }).done(function(retd){
                                console.log('Received: ' + retd);
                            }); // end ajax call
                            return false;
                        });//End change
```

Part 2 was a bit more involved.  Gibberish's tips helped out big time.  The SQL statement was incorrect.  I switched from using ID to just using the old name value stored in the object.

```
<?php
// Testing only.  This will show the values returned.
// die($_POST['action'] . $_POST['oldval']);
  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    if(class_exists('dbde_mysql')){

        $uName_db = new dbde_mysql;
         $uName_connect = mysqli_connect($uName_db->host, $uName_db->user, $uName_db->pass, $uName_db->db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($uName_db));
        $newUserName = $_POST['action'];
        $oldUserName = $_POST['oldval'];
        $uName_str = "UPDATE users SET users.username = '{$newUserName}' WHERE users.username = '{$oldUserName}'";
        if(mysqli_query($uName_connect, $uName_str)){
            $affectedRows = mysqli_affected_rows($uName_connect);
            die($affectedRows);
        }


        mysqli_close($uName_connect);


 }else{
         require_once('../.mysql.inc.php');
         $uName_db = new dbde_mysql;
         $uName_connect = mysqli_connect($uName_db->host, $uName_db->user, $uName_db->pass, $uName_db->db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($uName_db));
        $newUserName = $_POST['action'];
        $oldUserName = $_POST['oldval'];
        $uName_str = "UPDATE users SET users.username = '{$newUserName}' WHERE users.username = '{$oldUserName}'";
        if(mysqli_query($uName_connect, $uName_str)){
            $affectedRows = mysqli_affected_rows($uName_connect);
            die($affectedRows);
        }
         mysqli_close($uName_connect);

 }



?>
```